# ClassNotFound Exception while trying to run jar in unix server

Tags: java, unix, noclassdeffounderror

I created a executable jar of my Java project I tested the jar and it is working as expected in windows but when i try run the same jar in Unix..

```
java jar my.jar
```

..it is throwing me the error below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jar
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321) 
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
```

How to overcome the above error?

Comment: 1) *"Thank you in advance, Tom"*  Don't include noise in the body of questions.  2) Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: Thank you Andrew i will follow from my next post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be

```
java -jar my.jar
```

not the

```
java jar my.jar
```

See

- [java - the Java application launcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html)

Comment: Still i have the same exception

Comment: are you sure you have valid jar and you supplied `-jar` note: hyphen sign `-`

Comment: @tom No, you might have a similar exception. It won't be `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jar` anymore.

Comment: try `java -cp my.jar your.main.class.Name`

Answer (score 0):

In a runnable jar file , there will be a `MANIFEST.MF` inside the `META-INF` folder. Inside `MANIFEST.MF` there should be an entry `Main-Class: com.myapp.MyMainClass` . This will be created automatically if you using the jar command to make a runnable jar file.To be sure,unjar the jar and see if this entry is present.